# Why does HashMap.get(key) needs to be synchronized when change operations are synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I use the `.get(...)`, `.put(...)` and `.clear()` operations from multiple threads on one HashMap. `.put(...)` and `.clear()` are inside a `synchronized` block but `.get(...)` is not. I can't imagine that this will cause problems but in other code I've seen `.get()` is pretty much always synchronized.

relevant code for get/put

```
Object value = map.get(key);
if(value == null) {
  synchronized (map) {
    value = map.get(key); // check again, might have been changed in between
    if(value == null) {
      map.put(key, new Value(...));
    }
  }
}
```

and clear is just:

```
synchronized (map) {
  map.clear();
}
```

The write operations will invalidate caches because of the synchronized and the `get(...)` returns either null or an instance. I can't really see what could go wrong or what would improve by putting the `.get(...)` operation into a `synchronized(map)` block.

Comment: This is why the java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock was created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one simple scenario that would produce a problem on unsynchronized `get`:

- Thread A starts `get`, computes the hash bucket number, and gets pre-empted
- Thread B calls `clear()`, so a smaller array of buckets gets allocated
- Thread A wakes up, and may run into the index-out-of-bounds exception

Here is a more complex scenario:

- Thread A locks the map for an update, and gets pre-empted
- Thread B initiates a `get` operation, computes the hash bucket number, and gets pre-empted
- Thread A wakes up, and continues the `put`, and realizes that the buckets need resizing
- Thread A allocates new buckets, copies old content into them, and adds the new item
- Thread B wakes up, and continues the search using the old bucket index on the new array of buckets.

At this point, thread B is probably not going to find the right item, because it is very likely to be in a hash bucket at a different index. That is why `get` needs to be synchronized as well.

Comment: All of the above can happen in a _sequentially consistent_ execution of the program, but Java doesn't even guarantee SC. So even if all the problems described here were to be somehow avoided, `get` would _still_ have to be synchronized.